# How to protect query node(id : ID!) in Relay?

Tags: reactjs, security, graphql, relay

I'm new to Relay and GraphQL and was unable to find the answer. If I have to provide unique id for each object that implements Node interface (according to Relay specification) then how to protect data from leaking. What stops someone who have such id from fetching the data he should be unable to.

> client : React + Relay
> server : MongoDB + Prisma + GraphQL-Yoga

Let's assume we have

```
type PrivateStuff implements Node {
  id : ID!
  secretData : String!
}
```

What if someone brute force this id or steal it from user

```
query{
  node(id : "PrivateStuffId") {
    id
    secretData
  }
}
```

Are there any ways to protect this data?

Update: It's possible to increase security by encoding `id` before giving it to client and decode on request. But it won't secure the data if encoded id has leaked

Update: JWT with id in body may be an option. But it's hard to determine how long token should exist.

Comment: Do you have an authentication system ? Anyone can query your GraphQL API ?

Comment: I have simple auth system based on JWT. API uses CORS, so I guess anyone can query it.

Comment: Ok, if you have a JWT auth system, someone who is not authenticated will not be able to get the data even if he has the id. is that right ?

Comment: Just realized I can provide token via auth header using Network layer in Relay and not as a param in query. Thank you for a help!

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally found this [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/graphql-rest-authentication-authorization-basics-ct20). Long story short the client provides auth information in header and server uses middleware to process this data. Request headers can be accessed via `context.request`.